# create a template url-routing script

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-routing

I want to create an **url-routing** script using javascript as much as possible, but also accepting jQuery in the code. The js file has to change the url path (although I used location.hash instead of location.pathname) and the content of a div with the **view** id (from external files) accordingly.

Example configuration:

- **root/index.html**
- **root/tpl/home.html**
- **root/tpl/about.html**

home.html content:

```
<p>This is content of home page</p>
```

about.html content:

```
<p>This is the content of the about page </p>
```

What I have done so far:

```
'use strict';
var Router = {
root: '/',
routes: [],
urls: [],
titles: [],
navigate: function() {
    location.hash = this.root;
    return this;
},
add: function(thePath, theUrl, theTitle) {
    this.routes.push(thePath);
    this.urls.push(theUrl);
    this.titles.push(theTitle);
},
loading: function() {
    this.navigate();
    var r = this.routes;
    var u = this.urls;
    window.onload = function() {
        $("#view").load("tpl/home.html");
    };
    window.onhashchange = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            if (location.hash == r[i]) {
                $("#view").load(u[i]);
            }
        }
    };
}
};
Router.add("#/home", "tpl/home.html", "Home Page");
Router.add("#/about", "tpl/about.html", "About Page");
Router.loading();
```

Desired type of url:

```
http://mywebsite.com/
http://mywebsite.com/about
```

I know there are more than enough libraries that make the routing, like AngularJS and Crossroad, I want to know how this could be done.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: How to make the script with the mentioned behaviour because my does not work properly.

Comment: "Does not work properly" isn't very helpful. What behavior **are** you seeing?

Comment: First of all, it is made to change with hash, which I do not want because  I have to keep the url aspect for the user. Second, when clicking a link from base url to "#/about", the script loads about.html, but when clicking the back button, the scriot does not change back the template to home.html... This are some examples. What I want would be to make your own Router to have another fresh look, of course, if you wish.

Comment: A hash is part of the URL: it addresses a specific chunk of the resource addressed by the URL. It's a common pattern to use hashes in single page web apps, and in a properly constructed app, loading a URL with hash will display precisely the context that you want. It sounds like you also want to look at history manipulation in order for the back button to behave as you expect. All in all, this is outside the scope of a simple SO question. Narrow down your request, and in the meantime, look at some of those other routing libraries for inspiration.

Comment: If you want to manipulate history you can make use of [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) that allows you to push new history entries. You need to consider old browser, though.

Comment: This api may be a part of the router. And I need the router.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make this URL work - `http://mywebsite.com/about` - you need a server that knows how to route this request. Since the actual file name is `about.html` your server must know what to do with extensionless URLs.

Usually, the server uses the file extension as a clue for how to serve up content. For example, if it sees `file.php` it knows to use the PHP component,  for `.aspx` it knows to use the ASP.NET component, and for `.htm` or `.html` it knows to respond with plain HTML (and usually serves the file instead of processing it). Your server must have some rules for what to do with any request, whether it has an extension or not, but without an extension you need to provide an explicit routing rule for that request..

The capabilities for JavaScript to do routing are limited because it requires the user to already be on your site. You *can* do some interesting things if you parse the URL parameters or use hashes and use them for routing, but that still requires requesting a page from your site as the first step.

For example: the server is already doing some level of "extensionless routing" when you give it this request:

`http://mywebsite.com/`

The parts of the URL are:

- `http` - protocol
- (port 80 is implied because it is default HTTP port)
- `mywebsite.com` - domain AKA host
- `/` the path

The server sees `/` and uses what IIS calls a "default document" (I think apache calls it "default index" or "default page"). The server has been configured to return a file such as "index.html" or "default.htm" in this case. So when you request `http://mywebsite.com/` you actually may get back the equivalent of `http://mywebsite.com/index.html`

When the server sees `http://mywebsite.com/about` it may first look for a folder named `about` and next for a file named `about`, but since your file is actually named `about.html` and **is in a different folder** (`/tpl`) the server needs some help to know how to translate `http://mywebsite.com/about` into the appropriate request - which for you would be `http://mywebsite.com/#/about` so that it requests the routing page (assuming it is the default document in the web app root folder) so that the browser can parse and execute the JavaScript that does the routing. Capisce?

Comment: This is a plain sincere answer based upon a lot of work, but documenting will show that some statements are wrong. JavaScript capabilities are limited, but are enough for a good routing, as AngularJS framework may prove. I am using Apache server, but I don't want to use any server-side language to modify my route or the server response. Iframes are a not recommended tactic for developers, but AJAX and XMLXttpRequests are more than enough for a **router**.

Comment: The URL: `http://mywebsite.com/about` will only work if the server knows what to do for `about`. You need to make some change on your server to make this work, otherwise you will need to use an URL like `http://mywebsite.com/index.html#/about` (which you already figured out). The browser needs to get and parse the page & script before it can do any routing when using a pure-JS solution. The server would need to translate the request `http://mywebsite.com/about` into `http://mywebsite.com/#/about`.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested by [frontexpress](https://github.com/camelaissani/frontexpress).

My library fix your case like below:

```
// Front-end application
const app = frontexpress();

const homeMiddleware = (req, res) => {
  document.querySelector('#view').innerHTML = '<p>This is content of home page</p>';
}

app.get('/', homeMiddleware);

app.get('/home', homeMiddleware);

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  document.querySelector('#view').innerHTML = '<p>This is the content of the about page </p>';
});
```

Obviously, you can get the template files from the server.
The #view will be feeded as below:

```
document.querySelector('#view').innerHTML = res.responseText;
```

More detailed sample in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/camelaissani/d8151777519d82766ec84e93a7f85544)

Answer (score 0):

Your request reads like what you're attempting to do is to add a "path+file" ("/tpl/about.html") to a base url ("www.myhost.com"). If that's the case, then you need to dynamically extract the host name from your current document and then append the new URL to the existing base. You can get the existing host name by executing the following commands in javascript:

```
var _location = document.location.toString();
var serverNameIndex = _location.indexOf('/', _location.indexOf('://') + 3);
var serverName = _location.substring(0, serverNameIndex) + '/';
```

This will return a string like: "http://www.myhost.com/" to which you can now append your new URL. All of this can be done in javascript prior to sending to the server. 

 If you only want the server name, without the leading http or https, then change the last line to be:

```
var serverName = _location.substring(_location.indexOf('://') + 3, serverNameIndex) + '/';
```

Lets break your code down a little bit:

```
       function loading() {
```

"location.hash" is set based on the URL most recently clicked (www.myhost.home/#about). One essential question is, is this the action that you want, or do you want to pass in a value from the html for the onClick operation? It seems like that would be a more effective approach for you.

```
            var a = $.inArray(location.hash, routes),
                template = urls[a];
```

var a will be set to either -1 or the location of "location.hash" in the "routes array. If location.hash does not exist in routes, then a==-1 and the script will fail, because you're setting template = urls[-1]. You may want to move setting template to inside the "else" statement.

```
           if (a === -1) {
                location.hash = root;
                $("#view").load(urls[0]);
            }
            else {yada yada yada
            }
```

You could use a sequence in your html analogous to:

```
<a onclick="loading('#about')">Go to About Page</a>
```

Comment: What should I use to append path to serverName? HTML5 history API or something like window.pathname?

Comment: The behavior you detected may happen only to a person that does not know the Router. Another solution is to make every link begin with **hash**, like this ``<a href="#/about">About Us</a>``.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with what your answers and I have build the following **Router**. The only issue remains that it still uses **`location.hash`**

```
(function() {
    var Router = {
        root: '#/',
        routes: [],
        urls: [],
        titles: [],
        add: function(thePath, theUrl, theTitle) {
            this.routes.push(thePath);
            this.urls.push(theUrl);
            this.titles.push(theTitle);
        },
        navigate: function() {
            var routes = this.routes,
                urls = this.urls,
                root = this.root;

            function loading() {
                var a = $.inArray(location.hash, routes),
                    template = urls[a];
                if (a === -1) {
                    location.hash = root;
                    $("#view").load(urls[0]);
                }
                else {
                    $("#view").load(template);
                    if (a === 0) {
                        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    }
                    else {
                        window.scrollTo(0, 90);
                    }
                }
            }
            window.onload = loading;
            window.onhashchange = loading;
        }
    };
    Router.add("#/", "tpl/home.html", "Home Page");
    Router.add("#/about", "tpl/about.html", "About Page");
    Router.add("#/licence", "tpl/licence.html", "MIIT Licence");
    Router.add("#/cabala", "tpl/cabala.html", "Cabala Checker");
    Router.add("#/articles/esp", "tpl/article1.html", "ESP");
    Router.add("#/fanfics/the-chupacabra-case", "tpl/article2.html", "The Chupacabra Case");
    Router.navigate();
})();
```